# Add Workout route to HealthKit Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I have an array of CLLocation that I try to insert with a workout in HealthKit

So after inserting my workout to HealthKit with success, I create a workout builder and call the insertRouteData using my location array. But I always get this error from the completion :

*Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service on pid 1661 created from an endpoint" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service on pid 1661 created from an endpoint}*

I can not create workout route if the workout has been done in the past?. I have to add my location only in the delegate of CLLocationManager?

Comment: Hi Edgar, can you share some code?